# React Native on Android, ajax call with fetch fails

Tags: android, ajax, android-emulator, react-native, fetch-api

I am developing an Android app using React Native. I am testing my app on a Galaxy Nexus API 23 that is being emulated in Android Studio, running on a mac.

I wish to allow users to share information with each other. I am running a webserver with php and mysql, and I want the app to make requests to the server to share data between users.

I am trying to make a POST request to my development server using the Fetch API. My js code is below:

```
var AjaxEngine = {
    test: function() {
            return fetch('http://10.0.2.2/test.json')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    console.log(responseJson);
                    return responseJson.movies;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
};
```

called by `AjaxEngine.test();`

In my emulator I receive the following error:

> ExceptionsManager.js:70 TypeError: Network request failed
>           at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror     (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:23711:8)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:9740:15)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:25157:6)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:25015:6)
>           at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:25090:52
>           at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:8977:23)
>           at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:7065:23)
>           at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:6969:8
>           at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:6917:1)
>           at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:6968:1)

test.json consists of:

```
{
    "message":"hello world"
}
```

**The request is successful when I replace `'http://10.0.2.2/test.json'` with `'http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json'`, so the function itself is ok.**

`'http://localhost/test.json'` and `'http://127.0.0.1/test.json'` both load in a web browser, `curl`, and `wget`. I have also tried replacing the 10.0.2.2 with 127.0.0.1. I have also tried using my local ip (129.xxx.x.x)

What do I need to do to make these requests work? How do I access my development server running on localhost from the emulated android app?

Answer (score 0):

If you get curl to work, try the `-D` option, which writes the headers to a file. That way, you can see if both requests have f.ex. the same mime type.

> ```
>    -D, --dump-header <file>
>           Write the protocol headers to the specified file.
>
>           This option is handy to use when you want to store  the  headers
>           that  an  HTTP site sends to you. Cookies from the headers could
>           then be read in a  second  curl  invocation  by  using  the  -b,
>           --cookie  option! The -c, --cookie-jar option is a better way to
>           store cookies.
> ```